# Create Teams Meeting with Recurring Date using Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-live-meeting

I'm integrating microsoft Graph API into my application.
I have successfully integrate APIs for creating Team's meeting using the URL - https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendar/events
With the payload as in

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events
Prefer: outlook.timezone="Pacific Standard Time"
Content-type: application/json

{
  "subject": "Plan summer company picnic",
  "body": {
    "contentType": "HTML",
    "content": "Let's kick-start this event planning!"
  },
  "start": {
      "dateTime": "2017-08-30T11:00:00",
      "timeZone": "Pacific Standard Time"
  },
  "end": {
      "dateTime": "2017-08-30T12:00:00",
      "timeZone": "Pacific Standard Time"
  },
  "attendees": [
    {
      "emailAddress": {
        "address": "DanaS@contoso.onmicrosoft.com",
        "name": "Dana Swope"
      },
      "type": "Required"
    },
    {
      "emailAddress": {
        "address": "AlexW@contoso.onmicrosoft.com",
        "name": "Alex Wilber"
      },
      "type": "Required"
    }
  ],
  "location": {
    "displayName": "Conf Room 3; Fourth Coffee; Home Office",
    "locationType": "Default"
  },
  "locations": [
    {
      "displayName": "Conf Room 3"
    },
    {
      "displayName": "Fourth Coffee",
      "address": {
        "street": "4567 Main St",
        "city": "Redmond",
        "state": "WA",
        "countryOrRegion": "US",
        "postalCode": "32008"
      },
      "coordinates": {
        "latitude": 47.672,
        "longitude": -102.103
      }
    },
    {
      "displayName": "Home Office"
    }
  ],
  "allowNewTimeProposals": true
}
```

Now I want to set to allow user to create recurring meeting, how can I show this type of Functionality like as mentioned below.

tried with the below payload

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events
Prefer: outlook.timezone="Pacific Standard Time"
Content-type: application/json

{
  "subject": "Plan summer company picnic",
  "body": {
    "contentType": "HTML",
    "content": "Let's kick-start this event planning!"
  },
  "start": {
      "dateTime": "2017-08-30T11:00:00",
      "timeZone": "Pacific Standard Time"
  },
  "end": {
      "dateTime": "2017-08-30T12:00:00",
      "timeZone": "Pacific Standard Time"
  },
  "attendees": [
    {
      "emailAddress": {
        "address": "DanaS@contoso.onmicrosoft.com",
        "name": "Dana Swope"
      },
      "type": "Required"
    },
    {
      "emailAddress": {
        "address": "AlexW@contoso.onmicrosoft.com",
        "name": "Alex Wilber"
      },
      "type": "Required"
    }
  ],
  "location": {
    "displayName": "Conf Room 3; Fourth Coffee; Home Office",
    "locationType": "Default"
  },
  "locations": [
    {
      "displayName": "Conf Room 3"
    },
    {
      "displayName": "Fourth Coffee",
      "address": {
        "street": "4567 Main St",
        "city": "Redmond",
        "state": "WA",
        "countryOrRegion": "US",
        "postalCode": "32008"
      },
      "coordinates": {
        "latitude": 47.672,
        "longitude": -102.103
      }
    },
    {
      "displayName": "Home Office"
    }
  ],
  "allowNewTimeProposals": true
}
```

Comment: Please post the error as a text, not an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To allow users to create recurring meetings using the Graph API, you need to include the recurrence property in the payload when creating the event. The recurrence property specifies the recurrence pattern for the meeting.

Please refer this example to create a recurring event - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-post-events?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#example-3-create-a-recurring-event